# SAS software: How to delete observations with more than five zeros for the dependent variable

Tags: sas, filtering, data-cleaning

I have a consumer panel data with weekly recorded spending at a retail store. The unique identifier is household ID. I would like to delete observations if there occurs more than five zeros in spending. That is, the household did not make any purchase for five weeks. Once identified, I will delete all observations associated with the household ID. Does anyone know how I can implement this procedure in SAS? Thanks.

Comment: Post what you've tried and sample data. Process would be to count the number of consecutive weeks of 0, identify all id's where it's over 5 and then remove those IDs. Could be a data step or SQL solution or combination. Post sample data and what you've tried and someone can help beyond my general suggestions. General question -> General answer

Answer (score 0):

I think proc SQL would be good here.

This could be done in a single step with a more complex subquery but it is probably better to break it down into 2 steps.

1. Count how many zeroes each household ID has.
2. Filter to only include household IDs that have 5 or less zeroes.

`proc sql;

    create table zero_cnt as

    select distinct household_id,

 sum(case when spending = 0 then 1         else 0 end) as num_zeroes

    from original_data

    group by household_id;`

```
create table wanted as
select *
from original_data   
where household_id in (select distinct household_id from zero_cnt where num_zeroes <= 5);  
quit;
```

Edit:

If the zeroes have to be consecutive then the method of building the list of IDs to exclude is different.

```
* Sort by ID and date;
proc sort data = original_data out = sorted_data;  
by household_id date;
run;
```

Use the Lag operator: to check the previous spending amounts.

More info on LAG here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212547.htm

```
data exclude;   
  set sorted;   
  by household_id;    
  array prev{*} _L1-_L4;  
 _L1 = lag(spending);  
 _L2 = lag2(spending);  
 _L3 = lag3(spending);  
 _L4 = lag4(spending);  

  * Create running count for the number of observations for each ID;
  if first.household_id; then spend_cnt = 0;  
  spend_cnt + 1;  

  * Check if current ID has at least 5 observations to check. If so, add up current spending and previous 4 and output if they are all zero/missing;  
  if spend_cnt >= 5 then do;  
    if spending + sum(of prev) = 0 then output;  
  end;  
  keep household_id;
run;
```

Then just use a subquery or match merge to remove the IDs in the 'excluded' dataset.

```
proc sql;  
  create table wanted as  
  select *  
  from original_data;  
  where household_id not in(select distinct household_id from excluded);  
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you amend the code for the following situation. Zero counts for the outcome variable are okay as long as we don't have five zeros consecutively. Thanks again.